# How to make emacs truly full screen on start up?

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, kubuntu

I want emacs to be truly maximized on start up.

There are solutions to the problem that just make the emacs window width of the screen. That's not enough for me. I want the emacs window to be docked to the right upper corner of the screen, so that when I press there with a mouse, I will close emacs, not Firefox or Krusader or whatever is maximized in the background.

I tried to do it with Kwin - but no luck.

P.S. I'm using Kubuntu, and emacs is quite fresh one 23.2 or something like that.

Comment: @user maximized or full screen - which do you want? Your second paragraph is a bit vague.

Comment: There are some window manager dependent solutions. Which WM are you using? In Fluxbox, I use the `~/.fluxbox/apps` file to set maximized preference for specific applications.

Comment: I'm using KWM (it's KDE's default one). It has option "maximised" - but emacs window is not truely maximized: if You'll press "x" at the top right corner with a mouse - You'll close something else - not emacs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've taken this from somewhere on emacswiki, some time ago.
Note that I no longer use it, as I've switched to dwm to have everything fullscreen, but it used to work.

```
(defun fullscreen ()
       (interactive)
       (x-send-client-message nil 0 nil "_NET_WM_STATE" 32
                 '(2 "_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN" 0)))
```

If you want it to run on startup, you should be able to add

```
(fullscreen)
```

to your `.emacs`

EDIT: Rereading your question, I think this is not what you want. This will go really fullscreen, not maximized: you will not have any close button.

This one should do:

```
(defun fullscreen (&optional f)
  (interactive)
  (x-send-client-message nil 0 nil "_NET_WM_STATE" 32
             '(2 "_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT" 0))
  (x-send-client-message nil 0 nil "_NET_WM_STATE" 32
             '(2 "_NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ" 0)))
```

Now it's directly from http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FullScreen

Answer (score 3):

Here are two non-Lisp ways to achieve the same:

1. Alias your `emacs` command to `emacs -fs`. Add this line of code to your `.bashrc` file in your home directory:

   ```
   alias emacs='emacs -fs'
   ```

   Personally, I don't like this approach because I wouldn't want Emacs to start up in full screen all the time and would like some control.
2. My solution: In Ubuntu, you can assign a keyboard shortcut to 'full-screen' any window. This seems to be the most convenient and simple option. Besides, it has the advantage that the same shortcut also applies to all your applications.

Comment: +1 There's also `-mm` (short for `--maximized`) which will "maximize the first frame". The effects of using this option are a little less "drastic" than the `-fs` option (Emacs title bar and OS panels stay visible).

Answer (score 3):

Put `(w32-send-sys-command ?\xf030)`  on your `.emacs` file. I think it solves your problem.

(works on Windows only)

Comment: That's cool, only though I'm working in linux. But still -- sometimes I have to work in windows too. Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to mention. This solution is only for Windows.

Comment: Yep, I see the `w32` thing.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to toggle fullscreen in emacs with the F11 key, add the following to .emacs:

```
;; the following should give fullscreen mode when F11 is depressed
(defun fullscreen ()
 (interactive)
 (set-frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen
              (if (frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen) nil 'fullboth))
```

If you want the fullscreen emacs to be very minimal (no tool bar, scroll bar, or menu bar, also add:

```
(progn
  (if (fboundp 'tool-bar-mode) (tool-bar-mode -1))  ;; no toolbar
  (menu-bar-mode -1) ;;no menubar
  (scroll-bar-mode -1) ;; no scroll bar
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I currently use Emacs version 28.2 on Windows, and a minimal solution is adding the line below to the Emacs configuration at `~/.emacs.d/init.el` (different under unix)

```el
(set-frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen 'fullboth)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think emacs will respect gconf settings, so you could set /apps/emacs/maximize, but don't know if that will help on Kubuntu -- worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following on Linux:

```
(defun my-frame-toggle ()
    "Maximize/Restore Emacs frame using 'wmctrl'."
    (interactive)
    (shell-command "wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -btoggle,maximized_vert,maximized_horz"))
```

and then bind it to a key:

```
(global-set-key [(control f4)] 'my-frame-toggle)
```

If you want to start out maximized, you can just add a call to `my-frame-toggle` to the end of your .emacs file.

Comment: When I write your code, onto my .emacs file. It shows parser error.

Answer (score 0):

I found a funny solution:

```
emacs -nw
```

starts emacs in a console - and you can maximize console itself!